# IDing every descendent of a matrixfield

Tags: templating, matrix

[Medium](http://medium.com/) has a feature (that's likely the groundwork for their paragraph commenting, among other things) that adds an id to every tag inside of an article. Like so

[image: medium having an id on every paragraph]

I'm interested in replicating the behavior with Craft, in such a way that I can then write queries like `element = craft.entries.find(2).element.find(120)`

Comment: I might answer this myself if I get time, but for the moment I'll leave it

Answer (score 2):

Each block within your Matrix field already has an ID, which you can access via `block.id` within a for-loop on your Matrix field:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    ID: {{ block.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to be able to query directly for a specific Matrix block, you can use the [Low Blocks](https://github.com/low/lowblocks) plugin, which provides a `craft.lowBlocks.id()` function for accessing a block by its ID:

```
{% block = craft.lowBlocks.id(123) %}
```

Comment: I believe the block.id is only available after the page is saved.

Comment: After a bit of work on this, `block.id` isn't necessarily what I want. Particular when I'm outputting blocks from redactor, it would end up counting several paragraphs as a single block